# Where in Microsoft's Owin implementation is the authorization end-point for Linked In?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, owin, katana

If you look at Facebook authorization options in Katana, you'll see that it declares all the three url's, namely the *authorization endpoint*, the *access token endpoint*, and the *resource server endpoint*.

```
public FacebookAuthenticationOptions() : base("Facebook")
{
    this.Caption = "Facebook";
    this.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-facebook");
    base.AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive;
    this.Scope = new List<string>();
    this.BackchannelTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60.0);
    this.SendAppSecretProof = true;
    this.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth";
    this.TokenEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
    this.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/me";
}
```

Source: https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook/FacebookAuthenticationOptions.cs

However, while I could find the *access token endpoint* and the *user information endpoint* for Linked In in the Katana Linked In implementation of OAuth, I could not find the *authorization url*, i.e. the first url that the user will hit to see the OAuth2 dialog.

```
public class LinkedInAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<LinkedInAuthenticationOptions>
    {
        private const string XmlSchemaString = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string";
        private const string TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken";
        private const string UserInfoEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,formatted-name,email-address,public-profile-url,picture-url)";
```

And it isn't here either.

```
public LinkedInAuthenticationOptions() : base("LinkedIn")
{
    this.Caption = "LinkedIn";
    this.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-linkedin");
    base.AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive;
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("r_basicprofile");
    list.Add("r_emailaddress");
    this.Scope = list;
    this.BackchannelTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60.0);
}
```

https://github.com/RockstarLabs/OwinOAuthProviders/blob/master/Owin.Security.Providers/LinkedIn/LinkedInAuthenticationHandler.cs

Comment: https://github.com/RockstarLabs/OwinOAuthProviders/blob/master/Owin.Security.Providers/LinkedIn/LinkedInAuthenticationHandler.cs#L182

Comment: Thank you very much. :-)